# Digit recurrence square root

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, numerical-methods

I need to implement a digit recurrence square root for generic floating point format such that exp_size + mant_size + 1 <= 64.

I basically followed the implementation suggested here
[handbook of floating point arithmetic](https://books.google.it/books?id=baFvrIOPvncC&printsec=frontcover&dq=handbook+of+floating&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RuCDVfSoHOzU7Abv563IAg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=handbook%20of%20floating&f=false) in the software implementation of floating point operator.

I've tried to test my implementation (not an exhaustive test) and basically for format like 32 bit it looks like to work fine, while for format like mantissa = 10, exponent = 5 for the input x = 0.25 instead to give me 0.5 it gives me apparently 0.707031.

So i was wandering if for small format maybe the digit recurrence approach has some limits or not or... simply my implementation is bad...

I hope you can help me... it's a pain to implement this stuff from 0...

Comment: the FPU computations are done on higher bit count for mantisa and exponent ( i8087+ FPU's internal number representation is 80bit) and the result is then truncated to the output. If you mimic this you got the right answer. If you do not want to go this way you can use bin search approach (it is a bit slower due to need of multiply but the result should be much more precise)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what did you say. But basically "my" approach is to compute instead for mantissa_size digits, mantissa_size digits + 1, this is because the square root need 1 digit bit for correct rounding. But it sounds a little strange to me that with 10 bit mantissa precision (for example) and 5 of exponent i don't get the correct answer for the input 0.25.

Answer (score 0):

it is extremly hard to look at your code but you should:

1. **test all the operand combinations**

   - if it works for single example does not mean it works for all of them
2. check bit masks

   - you wrote when you use 32bit then result is fine
   - when use 10 then not
   - that is hinting overflow somewhere
   - **are you sure you have the right bit counts reserved/masked for R?**
   - R should be 2 bits more then Q (+1 bit for accuracy and +1 bit for sign)
   - and also you should handle R as twos complement
   - Q is half of the D bits and unsigned

Could not find your algorithm (that book you linked does not allow me further then page 265 where SQRT starts may be some incompatibility I Use good old Opera) but this is The closest one I found in Google (Non-Restoring-SQRT) in some PDF research and HW implementation on FPGA and after clearing the bugs and testing this is what I code in C++ and tested:

```
DWORD u32_sqrt(DWORD D) // 32bit
    {
    const int   _bits  =32;
    const DWORD _R_mask=(4<<(_bits>>1))-1;
    const DWORD _R_sign= 2<<(_bits>>1);
    DWORD Q=0; // u(_bits/2    ) result (quotient)
    DWORD R=0; // i(_bits/2 + 2) 2os complement (remainder) R=D-Q*Q
    for (int i=_bits-2;i>=0;i-=2)
        {
        if (DWORD(R&_R_sign)){ R=(R<<2)|((D>>i)&3); R+=(Q<<2)|3; }  // R< 0
         else                { R=(R<<2)|((D>>i)&3); R-=(Q<<2)|1; }  // R>=0
        R&=_R_mask; Q<<=1; if (!DWORD(R&_R_sign)) Q|=1;             // R>=0
        }
    return Q;
    }
```

Comment: I haven't done exhaustive test is it true, but basically for the case __ms = 23, __es = 8, it's the same algorithm of the book. I also checked the mask stuff and that should be fine. If you want i can pass you the book part of interest in pdf, maybe it make easier to understand the problem (i thought the book link was fine honestly...).

Comment: But anyway... what are your suggestion on my code so? you think it is the Reminder R the problem? Do you think there's a safer way to do the same computation?

Actually the core of the code anyway is the for loop. The variable name are taken from that book and the explanation is also reported there. If you think i should explain better something please let me know...

Comment: You can find the paper where the notation is the same as the mine one here http://www.researchgate.net/publication/4273059_Faster_floating-point_square_root_for_integer_processors

Comment: @Lukkio that paper is really vague no clear algorithm is there present they are only mentioned and compared their performance for specific platform nothing more. Just add to your question how you compute this (algorithm), add more comment to the code, also a good idea is to add the Language Tag (so the syntax highlight will work)

Comment: Do you mind if we chat so i can explain better my notation and algorithm? I tried to derive by myself and it still looks like to be correct... probably i miss something..

Comment: Never mind... i've solved... the loop is correct is the exponent computation that didn't work. I will update my code with more comments later after an exhaustive test.

Thank you for the support.